# How to reindex programmatically in Magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, reindex

I want to reindex all indexes in Magento2 from an external file, for this I created a external file as below :

```
...
    $indexers = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\ConfigInterface')->getIndexers();
    foreach($indexers as $indexer)
    {
        $actualIndexer = $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Indexer\IndexerInterface')->load($indexer['indexer_id']);
        $actualIndexer->reindexAll();
    }

...
```

When I run it on then only config index reindexed, not all.

I know it is not a good way to reindex but It is my custom module requirement, I want to integrate reindex code in my module save controller, so that when client save form there will be no indexing issue.

How to reindex all indexes?

Answer (score 1):

Try below code :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory
 */
protected $_indexerFactory;
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $_indexerCollectionFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory $indexerFactory,
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
){
   $this->_indexerFactory = $indexerFactory;
   $this->_indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

// you can call this function to do reindexing
public function reIndexing(){
   $indexerCollection = $this->_indexerCollectionFactory->create();
   $ids = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();
   foreach ($ids as $id) {
   $idx = $this->_indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
   $idx->reindexAll($id); 
   //$idx->reindexRow($id); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call this function wherever you need to reindex. If you make it static, you can include and call it from anywhere you want, because it is class-independent.

```
use Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand;
public function reIndexing()
{
    $obj                      = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $indexerCollectionFactory = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory");
    $indexerFactory           = $obj->get("\Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory");
    $indexerCollection        = $indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    $allIds                   = $indexerCollection->getAllIds();

    foreach ($allIds as $id)
    {
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create()->load($id);
        $indexer->reindexAll(); // this reindexes all
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be fantastic if there was a way to run this from a plane php script, not from within magento2.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `Magento\Indexer\Console\Command\IndexerReindexCommand::execute()` on how the console command does it. If you analyze the code you can up with something like:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory
 */
protected $indexerCollectionFactory;

/**
 * Foo constructor.
 * @param \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Indexer\Model\Indexer\CollectionFactory $indexerCollectionFactory
) {
    $this->indexerCollectionFactory = $indexerCollectionFactory;
}

/**
 * Run every indexer
 */
public function runEveryIndexer()
{
    $indexerCollection = $this->indexerCollectionFactory->create();
    foreach ($indexerCollection->getItems() as $indexer) {
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }
}
```

A small sidenote: I don't know your use case, but it might make more sense to only reindex the required indexers, because some indexers might take a long time to run and are not always required to.