# Need to run Reindex command in Controller (programmatically) in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex, programmatically

I need to run command php bin/magento indexer:reindex in Controller.

Comment: please refer : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/193159/how-to-reindex-programmatically-in-magento2

Comment: @RutveeSojitra the problem is that I need to call this command in code

Comment: means you don't want to reindexing?

Comment: @RutveeSojitra I want to reindex but I want to do this by calling the command. I do not want to wait for the page to refresh whem reindexing

Comment: @SavanPatel no working I don't want to wait for refresh page

Answer (score 1):

*Run Reindex command in Controller
Put below code into your controller and you can run when you need it*

```
public function reindexAll() {
    $indexerFactory = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Indexer\Model\IndexerFactory');
    $indexerIds = array(
        'catalog_category_product',
        'catalog_product_category',
        'catalog_product_price',
        'catalog_product_attribute',
        'cataloginventory_stock',
        'catalogrule_product',
        'catalogsearch_fulltext',
    );
    foreach ($indexerIds as $indexerId) {
        echo " create index: ".$indexerId."\n";
        $indexer = $indexerFactory->create();
        $indexer->load($indexerId);
        $indexer->reindexAll();
    }
}
```